# Ruby on Rails (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bundle

I am getting the following error whenever I type any command on all my rails applications. I working on a virtual machine in cloud 9. Any idea or guidance?

```
(master) $ bundle exec rspec spec/
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:541:in `read': Permission denied - /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/c9-0.1/root/lib/ruby/gems/specifications/multi_json-1.8.4.gemspec (Errno::EACCES)
        from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:541:in `load'
        from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:269:in `block (2 levels) in _all'
        from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:268:in `each'
        from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:268:in `block in _all'
        from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:267:in `each'
        from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:267:in `_all'
        from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:410:in `each'
        from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `find_all'
        from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `matching_specs'
        from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/dependency.rb:238:in `to_specs'
        from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
        from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
        from /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/c9-0.1/root/lib/ruby/gems/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your gems were installed with `sudo` access, which your current user (web runner?) lack the right perms to see the Ruby install dir.

I can't quite say why the gems were installed to a path like `/usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges` — perhaps this is part of your cloud host's setup?

1. Do you boot your own rails server out of your instance?  e.g. like you installed Unicorn, nginx, etc. on your own?  If so, you can use `rbenv` to install a ruby and gemset to a local path over which you have full permission control.

If you don't have scenario #1 above, then the setup may be misconfigured by the host, and you should open a ticket.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In order to boot a rails server I use the following command: rails s -p $PORT -b $IP. However, this command is giving the error on all the application I have. I will open a ticket maybe they can have a solution.

Comment: Since you boot your own server, you should consider taking control of your ruby and gemset.  See the install instructions a[rbenv on GitHub](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).  ***Once you do this install your error should stop***

Comment: @Loic pardon, but could I also ask you to upvote the answer?  I'm [having a bug with my reputation score](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215953/i-seem-to-have-lost-over-2500-today-could-this-be-on-purpose) and I was told that a vote would reset it.  Think of it this way, one vote will kind-of give me 2600+ reputation ;)  You can downvote me if you feel that's more fair

Comment: voting up requires 15 reputations, I do only have 10 so far. I got my issue fixed by cloud 9 though. This was due to a deployment regression that went with C9 latest release that was causing this issue and break new workspace creations.